# Unable to authorize Azure LogAnalytics Workspace

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

[image]I am trying to connect to my workspace in the Azure Portal. I am getting the error as

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'.

The creds object has fetched the Authentication Token and I have added resource permissions to my app as mentioned in this [link](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Tools/CSharp-Sdk)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;

namespace LogAnalytics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workspaceId = "**myworkspaceId**";
            var clientId = "**myClientId**";

            var clientSecret = "**myClientSecret**";
            //<your AAD domain>
            var domain = "**myDomain**";
            var authEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
            var tokenAudience = "https://api.loganalytics.io/";

            var adSettings = new ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings
            {
                AuthenticationEndpoint = new Uri(authEndpoint),
                TokenAudience = new Uri(tokenAudience),
                ValidateAuthority = true
            };

            var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain,clientId, clientSecret, 
                strong textadSettings).GetAwaiter().GetResult();            

            var client = new OperationalInsightsDataClient(creds);
            client.WorkspaceId = workspaceId;

            //Error happens below
            var results = client.Query("union * | take 5");

            Console.WriteLine(results);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add permission in the `Access control (IAM)` in your workspace?

Comment: Yes, The app which has the above mentioned ClientId and ClientSecret is added to the resource with the role of LogAnalyticsReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'.

According to the error message and the code you provided, you need to add permission in your registered application in Azure AD.

[image]

**Note**: If you want to add permission to application **you need to be admin**, and then you could use the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` to get Authentication Token and read log analytics.

However, if you are **not admin**, you could **delegate permission to user** and access to Azure AD with username and password.

To get authentication token with user, you could  can use the function `UserTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(nativeClientAppClientid, domainName, userName, password).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to get our credentials.