# Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights returns 'Forbidden' message for service principle

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-log-analytics, azure-fluent-api

I am trying to read insights of a resource in azure. I am getting the error as:

```
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

The service principle has been given 'Log Analytics Reader' role on the subscription of the workspace.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication.AzureCredentials credentials =
 Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
 "clientId", 
 "clientSecret", 
 "tenantId", 
 Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var client = new Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights.OperationalInsightsDataClient(credentials);
client.WorkspaceId = @"workspaceId";
var results = client.QueryWithHttpMessagesAsync("union * | take 5").Result;
```

The solution to [status code: unauthorised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604411/unable-to-authorize-azure-loganalytics-workspace) is using delegated permissions, but I need an authentication token without userinteraction.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-api-troubleshooting-authentication-errors#forbidden-error ..May it helps

Comment: Thank you Ajay, I have read your link and verified I am using the correct clientId and clientsecret: using the same AzureCredentials with a Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have given the service principle 'Log Analytics Reader' role on the subscription .Need to give the API permission for your service principle as well.

- Go to your **service principle**> **API permission** >**Add permission** > **APIs my organization uses.** Search for ***Log analytics API*** .

[image]

- And Add the below permission to your service principle.

[image]

- And **grant admin consent permission** to your service principle for the API permission.

[image]

once you have granted the permission for service principle you would be able to read the logs .

For more information on the same thing using `powershell` please refer this [Blog](https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/azure-ad-log-analytics-kql-queries-via-api-with-powershell/) .

Comment: Thank you very much! The blog was very informative, and it took me a 2nd try to actually get it to work. (the powershell is missing a call to Get-AzureAuthN ($resource))
But what actually tripped me up was the error: Message:  AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application. 

When registering a new application, theres an optional field for redirect uri. The platform i selected 1st was 'Public client/native (mobile&desktop)' and i left it blanc. The powershell assumes a 'Web app' with localhost as redirectUri. Can you confirm that this, or am I still not understanding somet